# Change who has the crown in multiplayer?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

In Super Mario Bros Wonder how do you change the crown (leader) in multiplayer without dying?

Answer (score 2):

I need to do additional vetting but anecdotal evidence of ways for players to change the leader without dying:

- Holding L + R to turn into a ghost will switch the leader (kind of a death but different than using obstacles)
- Player who was the highest and reached the flagpole first during the previous round will be the leader on the next level

Comment: I can confirm both of these are accurate.